# Devise - LogIn parameters invalid email and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to RoR and I used devise gem for authentication.

I have a login form which is created by command "rails g devise:views"

If I change the `form_for(:session,.......)` it shows invalid email and password and if I change to `form_for(:user,......)` it is working.

Questions:

1)Why only user resource not any other resource or controller because the first parameter is for only use for params i.e, params[:session][email].

2)Where is it documented in Devise gem docs?

Can anyone please help me with this issue ?

Thanks in advance !!!!Sorry for silly doubt!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully, since the reproduction steps are a little vague... (What do you mean by "If I changed the `form_for(...) ...`"? Which line of the auto-generated view are you changing?) but hopefully I can answer...

Comment: Your database probably contains a table called `users`, and a rails model called `User`. The `resource` that Devise is using is, therefore, called `user`. So the form needs to be for a `user`.

Comment: However, it is also possible to have a differently-named entity, e.g. `student`, or `teacher`, or `parent`, or `moderator`, or `staff`, or `guest`, or `admin`, .... You can even have multiple types of "user" in the same rails application. For instance, see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes) in the README, where it discusses having a `user` *and* an `admin`.

Comment: This is why, when generating the views with `rails g devise:views`, it actually says `form_for(resource, ....`, not e.g. "`form_form(:user, ...)" -- Because the same view might be used for multiple entities, and regardless there is no need for the code to repeat the resource name in multiple places.

Comment: @TomLord i didnt understand this part "Because the same view might be used for multiple entities, and regardless there is no need for the code to repeat the resource name in multiple places."

Comment: You might have two identical "login" forms that are used for "admins"as well as "normal users", depending on the context. So rather than repeat the same code twice, you have one view that says `resource` instead of saying `user` and `admin` explicitly, with every other line of code being identical.

Comment: So how can u achieve that and what u will write in controller and your form is in views for admin and normal users.How devise will know whether that whether the form is for admin or for  normal users how u will pass the params??

Comment: I think this question is getting a bit too broad for discussing in the comments section; your original question is now expanding into "how can I build a rails app with Devise?". I'd advise reading some documentation/watching a tutorial, and asking a more concise, specific SO question if you get stuck.

Comment: But the short answer is: See the link to the README I posted above. You can define multiple routes, e.g. `devise_for :users` **and** `devise_for :admins`. For example, this means you could have multiple URLs such as `/users/sign_in` **and** `/admins/sign_in`. Based on the route, Devise knows which type of user we're dealing with.